# Trouble with queryProductDetails() in flutter package in_app_purchase

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

I am trying to add subscriptions to my app for IOS. The code I am using works on android but not for IOS whenever I use
`final ProductDetailsResponse response = await InAppPurchase.instance .queryProductDetails({'standard', 'family'});`
it always returns an empty array when it shouldn't.
I think it has something to do with Apple having subscription groups but I'm not to sure. Here's the full function for a better understanding:

```
  Future<bool> makePurchaseIos(String productId) async {

    late ProductDetails standardPlan;
    late ProductDetails familyPlan;

    final ProductDetailsResponse response = await InAppPurchase.instance
        .queryProductDetails({'standard', 'family'});

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text("Got the following products: ${response.productDetails}"),
            ));

    for (ProductDetails product in response.productDetails) {
      if (product.id == 'standard') {
        standardPlan = product;
      } else if (product.id == 'family') {
        familyPlan = product;
      }
    }

    ///

    ProductDetails selectedProduct;
    if (productId == "standard") {
      selectedProduct = standardPlan;
    } else {
      selectedProduct = familyPlan;
    }

    final PurchaseParam purchaseParam =
        PurchaseParam(productDetails: selectedProduct);
    await InAppPurchase.instance.buyConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
    print(selectedProduct);
    return true;
  }
```

Whenever I try to press subscribe it returns the empty array which means the response from `queryProductDetails()` function is nothing. I do not know why this would be happening though as I am definitely giving it the correct subscription ID's

Comment: Have you agreed to the apple purchasing agreement and added tax documents along side a bank account?

Comment: @ReeceHarris I have just found out my client declined them which does seem to be the issue once the client has solved this I will let you know with an update.

Comment: Clients are difficult to work with lol

Comment: @ReeceHarris Couldn't agree more

Answer (score 1):

On the clients computer they had told me they had set up the banking, taxes and agreed to the terms and conditions. It turned out they hadn't so that's where it was going wrong however Apple does not give you an actual error message to inform you of this. If you have the same error double check the steps I have mentioned are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let check and make sure that you agreed to the all apple purchasing agreement, tax, banking... on appstoreconnect.

Comment: this is a duplicate answer, and has already been said. also your answer lacks details.